# Learning javaScript break Statement and stuck at understanding why an iteration behaves weird

Tags: javascript, break

Learning about break statement. i have the following code from a book i'm learning from:

```
for (const x of ['a', 'b', 'c']) {
    console.log(x);
    if (x === 'b') break;
    console.log('---')
}
// Output:
// 'a'
// '---'
// 'b'
```

Why does 'b' still print? The code in english, print each element x of ['a','b','c'] and if the element x is equals to b Stop! then print '---'. Where does the 'b' come from if i requested the iteration to stop?

Comment: you have to put your break before the `console.log(x)`

Comment: this type of problem can be solved with breakpoints and a debugger.

Comment: Statements execute in order.

Comment: yh i just realised, feel stupid.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple. In line two, you are logging the value of x *BEFORE* you are breaking the second iteration.

Comment: give this guy some credit. His solution is ON POINT!

Comment: i did, i now kind of understand how break works. experimenting and trying to understand in detail.

Answer (score 0):

It still prints 'b' because the `console.log(x)` is executed before the `if` condition is evaluated. Once the `if` statement is true it breaks out of the `for` loop and fin!